# Solve system of ODE by fractional finite difference method

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method, code

I am trying to solve the following system using fractional finite difference method:

[image]

where e=0.1, a=1.3, m=0.3, p=10, g=3, k=1 and s1, s2, s3 it was mentioned in this [paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/nleng-2020-0025/html) that it is calculated using the shooting technique.

I have written the code as follows

```
a = 1.3;
m = 0.3;
k = 1;
g = 3;
p = 10;
e = 0.1;
N = 100;
h = 1/N;
fractionalDifference[n_, s_, h_,u_] := (Sum[(-1)^(n - j) Binomial[n, j] u[h j]/h^s, {j, 0, n}]-u[0]/h^s)/Gamma[1 - s];

eqns = {fractionalDifference[3, 1/2, h, 
     F'''[t]] == (a/(a + 1)) (-F''[t] F[
         t] + (2 m/(m + 1)) (F'[t])^2 + (k/(m + 1)) H[t] - g C[t]), 
   fractionalDifference[2, 1/2, h, 
     H''[t]] == (a/(a + 1)) (F[t] H'[t] - (2 m/(m + 1)) F'[t] H[
         t] + (k/(m + 1)) F'[t] + g C[t]), 
   fractionalDifference[2, 1/2, h, C''[t]] == 
    p F[t] C'[t] - p (1 - m/(m + 1)) F'[t] C[t]};

bc = {F[0] == (1 - m/(m + 1)) e, F'[0] == 1, F''[0] == s1, H[0] == 0, 
   H'[0] == s2, C[0] == 1, C'[0] == s3};

grid = Range[0, 1, h];

sol = NDSolve[{eqns, bc}, {F, H, C}, {t, grid}];


Fsol = F /. sol[[1]];
Hsol = H /. sol[[1]];
Csol = C /. sol[[1]];

(*Plot the solutions*)
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{grid, Fsol}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "F[t]"}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotLabel -> "F[t]"]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{grid, Hsol}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "H[t]"}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotLabel -> "H[t]"]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{grid, Csol}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "C[t]"}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotLabel -> "C[t]"]
```

My question now is how are s1, s2, s3 calculated and is the code like this correct?

Comment: Do not use `C`,`N`,`K` etc. as the user define variable.